# Send an image onchange through AJAX

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input name="userfile" onchange="loadPlayerPhoto('1')" type="file" value="fotog">

function loadPlayerPhoto(photoid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: './auth/ajax.php',
        data: 'idp='+escape(photoid)+'&id=loadplayerphoto',
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#ppid'+photoid).html(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

when a user select the photo, it call that function. I need to send the photo via ajax. How can send it to the server?

Comment: What do you mean, "send the photo"?  Do you mean "upload a file" or "notify the server of which file was selected"?

Comment: If you mean upload the file, this is easier with a plugin eg http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

Comment: yeah i mean upload a file dinamically. I think it was more easy than configure a plugins. So i think i wont use it...tnx anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [AJAX Upload File Plugin](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/)

You could also look at the source code of [this page](http://www.diepbachduong.com/index.php/play/img), although I am not sure what the licencing is on this plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP as a server side language then you can use the below plugin -

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery-image-upload-and-crop-for-php/

You can also try below plugin if your server side language is not PHP -

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/AjaxMultiFileUpload